# how can i add event listener for all the <script> and <link> tag fetch calls invoked from my application landing html page

Tags: html, jquery, css, httpwebrequest

I want to intercept each script or link fetch call that my application html page invokes, is it possible to do that through an event listener.

Comment: You can't do that through an event listener. You could through a MutationObserver though, but it's very far from an ideal solution. Can you not amend the code which injects the `script`/`link` tags to do whatever it is you need?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan html page is loaded inside a iframe returned by a 3rdparty app which I have no control over, but when the script and link tag calls are invoked from the html inside that I frame , I want to intercept those calls and mutate the request headers. right now I am using cookie for that, but I'm looking for an alternate.

Comment: Is the content of the iframe hosted on the same domain as the parent window? If so, you can use a MutationObserver as I mentioned. If it's on a separate domain then what you're trying to do is impossible - you cannot access cross-domain iframe content from the parent window for security reasons.